# How make \parshape declared inside an environment to apply the next paragraph outside the environment?

Tags: macros, environments, paragraphs, parshape

I'm trying to do something like the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myenv}{%
  \parshape = 4
    0pt 0.5\textwidth
    0pt 0.5\textwidth
    0pt 0.5\textwidth
    0pt \textwidth
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
\end{myenv}%
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

I need the `\parshape` declared inside the `myenv` environment to apply to the next paragraph that follows the `myenv` environment. But obviously it doesn't do that right now. Is there anyway of getting that to work?

Comment: This seems like a very odd thing to do: could you give us a little more context?

Comment: I'm basically trying to do my own implementation of wrapping around a figure with text. So I declare the figure using an environment, which then generates the `\parshape` that create the empty space in which the figure will be put. But since the `\parshape` is declared inside the environment, it doesn't apply to the paragraph which comes first _after_ the environment. I know there's various packages for this but I've not been satisfied with them. Also, I like the challenge. =) `floatflt` and `wrapfig` do this with environments so it is possible (I think).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please always post complete documents not just fragments.

Note setting `\parshape` in LaTeX is almost always the wrong thing to do unless done with great care (almost all LaTeX constructs use the `\list` mechanism which relies heavily on `\parshape` not being messed with).

However

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{myenv}{%
  \gdef\foo{\parshape = 4
    0pt 0.5\textwidth
    0pt 0.5\textwidth
    0pt 0.5\textwidth
    0pt \textwidth}\aftergroup\foo
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
\end{myenv}%
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It was a complete example, but I forgot an additional linebreak so the beginning of the code got put into the running text above. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Cool, it works! Although it requires that `myenv` and the next paragraph are not separated by a linebreak, but that's a minor thing. Could you please explain how it works? I'm not familiar with `\gdef` and `\aftergroup`.

Comment: @gablin TeX resets the `\parshape` at each `\par`. This can be subverted (see for example `l3galley`), but I think I'd avoid that in LaTeX2e as things rely on `\par`'s behaviour.

Comment: @gablin `\gdef` makes a global definition so it is in force after the environment and `\aftergroup` inserts a token just after the current group ends.

Comment: I would have approached this a bit differently by putting the `\aftergroup\foo` in the closing part to the definition of the new environment.  Why does putting it into where you have work?

Comment: @A.Ellett I'd have put it there too but OP had it in the start, perhaps in the real code it's needed in the body of the environment as well as after. it works as `{\aftergroup\foo...}` is same as `{....\aftergroup\foo}` it doesn't matter where in the group the token is aftergrouped, it is executed just after the close in either case